# jQuery play Audio. Audio repeat every true or false answer

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

Audio need to play on every correct and incorrect answer.

```
// Span "correct!" or "wrong!"
                if(isRightAnswer) {
                    $parent.find('div.wpvq-explaination div.wpvq-true').show();
                    $('#audio1').get(0).play();

                } else {
                    $parent.find('div.wpvq-explaination div.wpvq-false').show();
                    $('#audio2').get(0).play();

                }
```

I have two audio files one for true and other for false. Need to play audio all time when it's a true or false. Now it's working on first 1-2 answers only.

```html
 <audio id="audio1" src="http://f5361a5c08a4c03f7c6f-acbeb9602bd0a56bf9c1a6bed3d8280b.r27.cf2.rackcdn.com/RightSound2%202.mp3" ></audio>

<audio id="audio2" src="http://f5361a5c08a4c03f7c6f-acbeb9602bd0a56bf9c1a6bed3d8280b.r27.cf2.rackcdn.com/wrongSound2.mp3" ></audio>
```

It's working, but it's not repeating every true and false. Work at once only.

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGlIj.png)

Comment: can you add the code in detail?

Comment: please check your selectors, the first one selects an element by id and the second one selects a collection of elements by classname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have is that once the sound has played the position of the track does not return to the start. Hence calling `play()` again does nothing as the audio is at the end of the track.

To force this, set `currentTime = 0` before calling `play()`:

```js
var correctAudio = $('#audio1').get(0);

$('#right-answer').click(function() {
  correctAudio.currentTime = 0;
  correctAudio.play();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id="audio1" src="http://f5361a5c08a4c03f7c6f-acbeb9602bd0a56bf9c1a6bed3d8280b.r27.cf2.rackcdn.com/RightSound2%202.mp3"></audio>

<button id="right-answer">Right answer</button>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're saying

Comment: ` $('.wpvq-answer').click(function() {

$('.wpvq-answer.wpvq-answer-true').siblings().addClass("wpvq-answer-css");


$('.wpvq-answer.wpvq-answer-false').addClass("wrong-css");

});`  Possible to add audio 1 and audio 2 in this click function?  class 1, .wpvq-answer.wpvq-answer-true | Class 2, .wpvq-answer.wpvq-answer-false

Comment: Working fine.. Thanks